# Searching from two columns is extremely slow

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**SOLVED**:  Andy Lester pointed my to the right direction, it was due to poor index definitions.

There is a part of a query which is causing my a lot of trouble:

```
 SELECT i.id
 FROM items AS i
 LEFT JOIN tag_rel as tr2 ON (tr2.item = i.id)
 LEFT JOIN tags  AS t2 ON (t2.id = tr2.tag)
 WHERE t2.name LIKE 'chocolate'
 GROUP BY i.id
```

**items** is the "items table

**tag_rel** is the relationship between the item and the tag

**tags** contains the name of the tag

So the query above works fine, as it should: it returns the items tagged as chocolate

But here is what im doing which slows the query down a lot (10 seconds+) so I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong :-/

```
 SELECT i.id
 FROM items AS i
 LEFT JOIN tag_rel as tr2 ON (tr2.item = i.id)
 LEFT JOIN tags AS t2 ON (t2.id = tr2.tag AND t2.sec_corrected = 0)
 LEFT JOIN tags AS t3 ON (t3.sec_corrected = tr2.tag AND t3.sec_corrected > 0)
 WHERE (t2.name LIKE 'choclate' OR t3.name LIKE 'choclate')
 GROUP BY i.id
```

**sec_corrected** is a column in the "tags" table which contains the id of another tag, ie:

```
Tags table structure:
id 1   name choclate   sec_corrected 2
id 2   name chocolate   sec_corrected 0
```

Just to **clarify**, i want get the "items" which are tagged as"chocolate" if the user searches for either "chocolate" or "choclate", since "choclate" has been corrected as "chocolate".

I have also tried with only one LEFT JOIN but it's still slow:

```
 SELECT i.id
 FROM items AS i
 LEFT JOIN tag_rel as tr2 ON (tr2.item = i.id)
 LEFT JOIN tags AS t2 ON (t2.id = tr2.tag OR t2.sec_corrected = tr2.tag)
 WHERE (t2.name LIKE 'choclate')
 GROUP BY i.id
```

Any ideas?

Thank you so much!

Comment: can you use explain {your query} and share the result ?

Comment: `WHERE (t2.name LIKE 'choclate' OR t3.name LIKE 'choclate')`?? why not use Wild card to do the search for starters for example 
`WHERE (t2.name LIKE 'choclate%' OR t3.name LIKE 'choclate%') or 
`WHERE (t2.name LIKE '%cho%' OR t3.name LIKE '%cho%') sounds like you need to read up more on how to sturcutre a query and how to use Joins

Comment: I think they should be full joins in the first query - your WHERE clause requires the right-most table to be present anyway.

Comment: It's probably not relevant to your issue but using `LIKE` as synonym for `=` leads to fairly confusing code.

Comment: Also, you may find a performance benefit in splitting this into several queries. First find all tags where the name is `LIKE 'chocolate'`, get the IDs of those tags, and then use `IN` in your final query. You don't then need to join to `tags`, just `tag_rel`.

Comment: If you want us to help optimize a query, **you need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com ASAP.

Comment: I updated my post with the full query, hope this helps!

Comment: THanks @AndyLester it was all about cleaning up the indixes :)

Answer (score 0):

Without the explain it is a bit Try-And-Error, but normally with a simple "OR" clause you can block the index usage. LIKE is overkill, use "=" when no pattern is given.

Simple solution is to split it into two INNER JOINs with a union. Ugly, but often helpful.

```
SELECT i.id
FROM items AS i
INNER JOIN tag_rel as tr2 ON (tr2.item = i.id)
INNER JOIN tags AS t2 ON (t2.id = tr2.tag AND t2.sec_corrected = 0)
WHERE (t2.name = 'choclate')

UNION
SELECT i.id
FROM items AS i
INNER JOIN tag_rel as tr2 ON (tr2.item = i.id)
INNER JOIN tags AS t3 ON (t3.sec_corrected = tr2.tag AND t3.sec_corrected > 0)
WHERE (t3.name = 'choclate')
```

that could help a lot.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answery! Yeah, I'm actually using LIKE '$search%'. Do you know if there is any alternative to UNION? Because my query is actually quite extense... is there an equivalent to UNION for two LEFT JOINs?

Comment: This fruit is sour, I know. The only way is using dynamic Query parts for composing the two halfs of the query. Just try it with pure SQL-Text, maybe you are lucky and it doesn't help in your scenario. Just add the explains, if that is not the solution. But real LEFT JOINS are slower.